# Error "Unknown primary key for table <join_table> in model <JoinTable>" when i using "collection_check_boxes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, primary-key

I put collection_check_boxes for HABTM case, and i getting this error:

```
Started POST "/cars" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-18 13:11:23 -0300
Processing by CarsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"b6MdXqwIDw2GvgEGvY1dGEr3v08+h9IkC5UPFyjX6MA=", "car"=>{"brand"=>"4", "model"=>"1117", "version"=>"8417", "license_plate"=>"hjg1234", "year"=>"133", "year_fabrication"=>"134", "steelplated"=>"false", "price"=>"12.34", "car_body_type_id"=>"2", "car_gearshift_id"=>"1", "condition"=>"new", "ports_number"=>"2", "color"=>"31", "car_fuel_type_id"=>"3", "renavam"=>"123421352", "optional"=>"", "tag_ids"=>["2", "4", "6", ""]}, "commit"=>"Confirmar"}
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" IN (2, 4, 6)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey (Unknown primary key for table cars_tags in model CarsTag.):
  app/controllers/cars_controller.rb:62:in `create'


  Rendered /home/yanksan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@carbon/gems/actionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /home/yanksan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@carbon/gems/actionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /home/yanksan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@carbon/gems/actionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /home/yanksan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@carbon/gems/actionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (15.6ms)
```

**Added code:**

View:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name %>
```

Controller (added tag_ids: []):

```
def car_params
  params.require(:car).permit(:carname, :brand, :model, :version, :year, :year_fabrication, :condition, :mileage,
                              :price, :color, :optional, :license_plate, :steelplated, :car_body_type_id,
                              :car_gearshift_id, :ports_number, :car_fuel_type_id, :renavam, tag_ids: [])
end
```

...

```
def create
  @user = User.find(current_user)
  @car = @user.cars.new(car_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @car.save
      CarsUser.where('user_id = ? AND car_id = ?', current_user, @car).update_all(date: Time.now)
      car = @user.cars.find(@car)
      format.html { redirect_to car, notice: 'Car was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @car }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Car model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :cars_tags
end
```

Tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars_tags
  has_many :cars, through: :cars_tags
end
```

CarsTag model:

```
class CarsTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

I have anothers associations like this in my code, but only place i get error is here when i use collection_check_boxes.

Rails version:
**4.0.8**

Ruby version:
**2.1.2p95**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried the approaches[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056162/getting-unknown-primary-key-for-table-while-the-id-is-there)?

Comment: But what i do not understand is why i need primary_key in join table? when i generate join tables i never bothered with it, as the guides of rails say. You have any idea why this now?